# JavaFX - Creating basic jumping mechanic

Tags: javafx-8, physics

I've been looking for awhile now for someone who had created a good example of making good physics in JavaFX, or even just a 'basic jumping mechanic' as the title says. I can't really find any information on it and I'm not really sure how to implement the idea.
All I want is a basic example, or just an explanation, or even just a point in the direction of what element of JFX I'm going to use.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is off-topic for this forum, however... See https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842. Also read [this](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html), which relies on [this previous post](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you already have some sort of game loop that ticks 60 times a second such as the `AnimationTimer`. If you want the jump height to be something like 200 pixels, you need to set and objects y-velocity (velocity is added to the objects location every tick) to a large negative number (as the object is moving upwards) and add a smaller amount every tick to this velocity until it hits zero, (this will be the top of the jump) and then keep adding this value to the y-velocity until it reaches the ground or collides with something. (This value will be your gravity constant)

In essence, you need to set the y-velocity to a high value then take away small increments every tick to slow the jump until the y-velocity hits 0, then begin adding the gravity constant again until the object hits the ground, hope this helps :)